# Best case and worst case time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given the following pseudo code for an array A

```
x = 0
  for i = 0 to n - 2
    for j = i to n - 1
       if A[i] > A[j]:
          x = x + 1
  return x
```

Is the worst case complexity O(n^2) or Theta(n^2) and why? I don't seem to understand the difference between the two.

As for the best case complexity, is it not the same as the worst case complexity because the algorithm still has to run through the same lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dominating operation in this algorithm is comparison `A[i] > A[j]`. This comparison is **always** done n^2 times.

O(n^2) means that this is worst-case complexity. If you use O notation you say that this complexity could be better in best-case.

Theta(n^2) means that this is the complexity in **all** cases.

So the answer is: the complexity is Theta(n^2) because in both best- and worst-case it's n^2.

See: [Big-Theta notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation) and [Big-O notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The comparison is **always** executed (n - 1) * (n+2) / 2 times which certainly is θ(n^2)